# How To Align Ok Button Of A Dialog Pane In Javafx?

Tags: javafx, dialog, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to align i.e Position CENTER an OK button of a DialogPane. I have tried the below code but its not working.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
DialogPane dialogPane = dialog.getDialogPane();
dialogPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #fff;");

        // Set the button types.
ButtonType okButtonType = new ButtonType("Ok", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
ButtonType cancelButtonType = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(okButtonType, cancelButtonType);
dialogPane.lookupButton(cancelButtonType).setVisible(false);

        // Testing
Button okButton = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(okButtonType);
okButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        // End Testing

dialog.showAndWait();
```

Comment: Ok button is visible at bottom right of dialog, which is its default feature, but I want it to be shown at bottom center of dialog.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add the extra information to the question.  Thanks!  (And please make the code a complete program - that helps people reproduce what you did, and provide you with a good answer).  See [help] for how to write a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Centering buttons in the ButtonBar of a Dialog is actually surprisingly difficult to achieve in a non-hacky way.

Below is the best solution I could come up with.  It relies upon a [dynamic CSS lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookup-java.lang.String-) of the HBox for the button container, to which it then adds a spacer region on the right to push the buttons to the left (the default ButtonSkin implementation already places an implicit spacer of the left which pushes the buttons to the right, which I determined using [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/)).  The combination of the left and right spacers end up aligning the buttons in the center.  The solution also overrides the ButtonBar creation to stop the ButtonSkin internally reordering and performing additional layout of buttons, as, when it does that, you can't really reliably customize the layout yourself.

[image: centered button]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Optional;

public class CenteredDialogButtons extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Button show = new Button("Show Dialog");

        Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        DialogPane dialogPane = new DialogPane() {
            @Override
            protected Node createButtonBar() {
                ButtonBar buttonBar = (ButtonBar) super.createButtonBar();
                buttonBar.setButtonOrder(ButtonBar.BUTTON_ORDER_NONE);

                return buttonBar;
            }
        };
        dialog.setDialogPane(dialogPane);
        dialogPane.getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.OK);
        dialogPane.setContentText("Centered Button");

        Region spacer = new Region();
        ButtonBar.setButtonData(spacer, ButtonBar.ButtonData.BIG_GAP);
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        dialogPane.applyCss();
        HBox hbox = (HBox) dialogPane.lookup(".container");
        hbox.getChildren().add(spacer);

        show.setOnAction(e -> {
            Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
            if (result.isPresent() && result.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                System.out.println("OK");
            }
        });

        StackPane layout = new StackPane(
                show
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(50));

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The reason I don't quite like this solution is that the dynamic CSS lookups kind of violate API encapsulation, as the CSS structure of the JavaFX scene graphs for controls such as button bars is not really part of their public API.  However, I don't think it is really possible to get centered buttons in a ButtonBar using the existing public APIs for JavaFX 8 and a default ButtonBar skin.

An alternate approach would be to create a custom skin for the ButtonBar associated with the dialog, but that approach is quite difficult and I wouldn't recommend it for this task.

Basically, the takeaway from all this is, just leave the default button layout and order for dialogs whenever you can, rather than trying to customize the dialog button layout.  If you do want to have completely customized layout to the level of things like button placement, then you may be better off just creating your own custom dialog class by subclassing Stage rather than basing your custom dialog implementation on the in-built dialog class.

Related, but slightly different information is in:

- [Enter Key Event Is Not Working On Dialog In Javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458089/enter-key-event-is-not-working-on-dialog-in-javafx)

Answer (score 5):

I tried to center OK button in `Alert` and I am not sure if this is bug or feature (Java8) but it was possible to center single button by setting new one:

```
alert.getButtonTypes().set(0, new ButtonType("OK", ButtonBar.ButtonData.LEFT));
```

As long as there is only one button with `ButtonData.LEFT`, it is centered in the middle of button panel. Obviously this solution does not work for panel with multiple buttons, but it might help to position single OK button.

Comment: thats really weird, cause Lorenzos solution worked fine for 2 buttons, but not for three, so i did this exact thing after adding the buttons, and now all 3 are centered

edit: however, as soon as I change the button data, they re arrange and are off center

Answer (score 2):

Add this method to your code and call it when you need to align the buttons in a Dialog or Alert:

```
    private void centerButtons(DialogPane dialogPane) {
      Region spacer = new Region();
      ButtonBar.setButtonData(spacer, ButtonBar.ButtonData.BIG_GAP);
      HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
      dialogPane.applyCss();
      HBox hboxDialogPane = (HBox) dialogPane.lookup(".container");
      hboxDialogPane.getChildren().add(spacer);
   }
```

Call it in this way: `centerButtons(dialog.getDialogPane);`

Comment: this does not work for more than 2 buttons?

Answer (score 1):

It's a kind of hack, but you could just do something like this:

```
okButton.translateXProperty().bind(okButton.prefWidthProperty().divide(-2));
```

The DialogPane is horizontal centered,  so subtracting the okButton's half width will do the trick.
But I think this is a really dirty solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @ManuelSeiche's answer, here is how to compute exact distance to the center:

```
@FXML private Dialog<ButtonType> dialog;
@FXML private ButtonType btClose;

@FXML
private void initialize()
{
    dialog.setOnShown(event ->
    {
        Platform.runLater(() ->
        {
            Button btnClose = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(btClose);
            HBox hBox = (HBox) btnClose.getParent();
            double translateAmount = hBox.getWidth() / 2.0 - btnClose.getWidth() / 2.0 - hBox.getPadding().getLeft();
            btnClose.translateXProperty().set(-translateAmount);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Centering a button(s) is actually quite easy (nonetheless it could be simpler and better documented). It all comes down to “magical” `buttonOrder` string passed to `ButtonBar`'s `setButonOrder(String)` method.

But first, the essential code snippet:

```java
@Override public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    // …
    var button = new ButtonType("Roger!", ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE);
    var dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.setDialogPane(new DialogPane() {
        @Override protected Node createButtonBar() {
            var buttonBar = (ButtonBar)super.createButtonBar();
            buttonBar.setButtonOrder("L_O_R");
            return buttonBar;
        }
    });
    dialog.getButtonTypes.addAll(button);
    var pane = dialog.getDialogPane();
    // Add whatever is needed to the pane here…
    // …
    dialog.showAndWait();
}
```

**Explanation**: the wrapping `start(Stage)` method is of course `Application`'s start method. First I create a button of OK/DONE type and then a `Dialog` instance. Nothing unusual so far.

And now: normally, after dialog gets created, we just add buttons and the content to dialog's pane. But here I actually *create and set the pane* first and a slightly modified one.

As you can see, I create anonymous class extending `DialogPane` and immediately set it as dialog's pane. What needs to be done in here, is to override one single method `createButtonBar`, and only for one, yet critical to our expectations, purpose: **to change the way the button bar layouts its children (i.e. buttons)**. In this particular case I used the string '"L_O_R"' (not LOTR ;-).

So what is it? It's not clearly documented, but if to look at [ButtonBar Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBar.htm), you will notice these few lines:

> **Windows:**  L_E+U+FBXI_YNOCAH_R
>
> **Mac OS:**   L_HE+U+FBIX_NCYOA_R
>
> **Linux:**    L_HE+UNYACBXIO_R

and accompanying pictures of buttons laid out on these OS-es. Each letter represents button type, and as per [ButtonData.OK_DONE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBar.ButtonData.html#OK_DONE) `OK_DONE` type has assigned letter `O`, while `L` and `R` mean left and right position respectively. The underscore `_` is a spacer or gap. So with the string `L_O_R` we are saying: *put buttons marked as LEFT on the left, those marked as RIGHT on the right, and those marked as OK_DONE just in between (because two surrounding gaps)*. Of course you can mix other types as it pleases you, so for instance you could pass `L_YXOCN_R` or whatever else you need.

If the `Dialog` had `setButtonOrder(String)` method, it would be much simpler to achieve desired effect. Anyway it's simpler that creating artificial spacers or messing with horizontal translations.