# Add text under buttons in Dialog

Tags: javafx, dialog

I was wondering if there is a way to display some text (like a info) under the buttons of a Dialog ? I've looked in many places, but even to align the buttons seems messy (from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36009764/how-to-align-ok-button-of-a-dialog-pane-in-javafx)).

This is what I got for now. I just want the "Set my choice ..." text under the 2 buttons.

[image: Dialog simple]

I looked for a function in the documentation that could help me display the way I want (like "`getButtonBar()`" or something like that) with no chance. Also creating a new `ButtonBar` seems a bit complicated for what I want to achieve.

I also tried to create a stage that could look like a dialog, but I needed the result incoming from clicking "Yes / No" in the same way the `Dialog`s do.

Is there any way to achieve want I want ? Or do I have to build it completely myself ? Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just override the `createButtonBar()` method of `DialogPane`:

```
DialogPane pane = new DialogPane() {
    @Override
    public Node createButtonBar() {
        VBox vbox = new VBox(5);
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        vbox.getChildren().add(super.createButtonBar());
        vbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Additional text"));
        return vbox ;
    }
};
```

Here's a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomDialogPaneTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Show Dialog");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            DialogPane pane = new DialogPane() {
                @Override
                public Node createButtonBar() {
                    VBox vbox = new VBox(5);
                    vbox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
                    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
                    vbox.getChildren().add(super.createButtonBar());
                    vbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Additional text"));
                    return vbox ;
                }
            };

            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("A check box");
            pane.setContent(checkBox);
            pane.setHeaderText("The header");
            pane.getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.YES, ButtonType.NO);

            Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
            dialog.setDialogPane(pane);
            dialog.showAndWait().ifPresent(System.out::println);
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane(button);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @James ! I didn't think about overriding it directly, and learnt that the pane of the Dialog was a BorderPane. Again, thanks !