# JavaFX FXML Dialog - can't close it with the X button

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm expected to finish a JavaFX dialog. I added the controller class to the ready FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>


<Dialog fx:id="dialog"
    fx:controller="myapp.AddDialogController"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <dialogPane>
        <DialogPane prefWidth="400.0" prefHeight="300.0">
            <stylesheets>
                <URL value="@/css/styles.css" />
            </stylesheets>
            <content>
                <VBox>
                    <Label text="Add some content here..."></Label>
                </VBox>
            </content>
        </DialogPane>
    </dialogPane>
</Dialog>
```

Now, when I'm trying to close the dialog with the X button provided by my desktop environment, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution - Add Buttons to your Dialog**

See the answer to:

- [Enter Key Event Is Not Working On Dialog In Javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458089/enter-key-event-is-not-working-on-dialog-in-javafx)

> I also recommend setting at least a CANCEL_CLOSE button or OK_DONE button in your JavaFX Alert, otherwise the user may have a difficult time actually closing the alert as the dialog will probably not respond to key presses as the user expects.

The same is likely true with trying to use the operating system's X button in the window frame to close the stage.

**Background Info**

To further understand the behavior, read up on the dialog closing rules in the [Dialog javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html):

> It is important to understand what happens when a Dialog is closed,
>   and also how a Dialog can be closed, especially in abnormal closing
>   situations (such as when the 'X' button is clicked in a dialogs title
>   bar, or when operating system specific keyboard shortcuts (such as
>   alt-F4 on Windows) are entered). Fortunately, the outcome is
>   well-defined in these situations, and can be best summarised in the
>   following bullet points:
>
> - JavaFX dialogs can only be closed 'abnormally' (as defined above) in two situations:
>
>   1. When the dialog only has one button, or
>   2. When the dialog has multiple buttons, as long as one of them meets one of the following requirements:
>
>      1. The button has a `ButtonType` whose `ButtonBar.ButtonData` is of type `ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE`.
>      2. The button has a `ButtonType` whose `ButtonBar.ButtonData` returns true when `ButtonBar.ButtonData.isCancelButton()` is called.
> - **In all other situations, the dialog will refuse to respond to all close requests, remaining open until the user clicks on one of the
>     available buttons in the DialogPane area of the dialog.**
> - If a dialog is closed abnormally, and if the dialog contains a button which meets one of the two criteria above, the dialog will
>     attempt to set the result property to whatever value is returned from
>     calling the result converter with the first matching ButtonType.
> - If for any reason the result converter returns null, or if the dialog is closed when only one non-cancel button is present, the
>     result property will be null, and the `showAndWait()` method will return
>     `Optional.empty()`. This later point means that, if you use either of
>     option 2 or option 3 (as presented earlier in this class
>     documentation), the `Optional.ifPresent(java.util.function.Consumer)`
>     lambda will never be called, and code will continue executing as if
>     the dialog had not returned any value at all.

So, without buttons in the dialog, it can't be closed...

**Answer to Follow-up Questions**

> And can I set the button type from FXML?

Maybe, I don't know, I've never tried it.  I wouldn't advise it anyway, instead I'd advise just setting the button types from code.  Honestly, I would probably only define the content pane of the dialog in FXML (e.g. just the VBox part of your FXML and it's subelements) and leave the rest of the enclosing Dialog definition in Java code.  I'm surprised defining a Dialog in FXML even works, but it does :-)  However, you can't open FXML with a Dialog as a root XML element in SceneBuilder (and the ability to use SceneBuilder to define your UI is IMO one of best reasons for using FXML in the first place).

**Sample Solution**

Here is a sample for a dialog definition for a dialog which can be closed either by a button in the dialog or by a key combination or a clicking on the close icon in the dialog frame provided by the operating system:

*AddDialogController.java*

```
package myapp.ui;

public class AddDialogController {}
```

*DialogDisplayApp.java*

```
package myapp.ui;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DialogDisplayApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
                getClass().getResource(
                        "add-dialog.fxml"
                )
        );

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(new Label("Main Window")), 600, 400));
        stage.show();

        Dialog dialog = loader.load();
        dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(
                ButtonType.CLOSE
        );

        dialog.initOwner(stage);
        dialog.showAndWait();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*myapp/ui/add-dialog.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Dialog?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<Dialog fx:id="dialog"
        fx:controller="myapp.ui.AddDialogController"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <dialogPane>
    <DialogPane prefWidth="400.0" prefHeight="300.0">
      <content>
        <VBox>
          <Label text="Add some content here..."></Label>
        </VBox>
      </content>
    </DialogPane>
  </dialogPane>
</Dialog>
```